# linked servers Access Denied error with an out-of-process OLEDB provider

Tags: sql, linked-list, out-of-process

I have an OLEDB for OLAP provider which I am trying to set up a linked server with. For some reason I cannot set the provider to run in-process (by checking the "Allow inprocess" option) as it uses some customized .NET assembly which SQL server seems to have problem to load (although I have run `CREATE ASSEMBLY` successfully). When I'm trying to run it as an out-of-process linked server, I am getting the following errors:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "K2" reported an error. Access denied.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "K2".
```

(Note the same error happens for Microsoft MSOLAP provider as shown above).

Further tracing of the errors shown the Access denied error happens on a IColumnsInfo::GetColumnInfo() call which is after the query has been executed successfully.

I have tried setting the permissions based on the following links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/08/19/permissions-needed-to-set-up-linked-server-with-out-of-process-provider.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Linked+Servers/73794/

But those don't work. Just wonder whether anybody else has experienced this issue.